# How to combine two columns in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe "df" like below:

```
Samples Status  last_contact_days_to    death_days_to
Sample1 Alive   [Not Available]       [Not Applicable]
Sample2 Dead    [Not Available]             724
Sample3 Dead    [Not Available]            1624
Sample4 Alive      1569               [Not Applicable]
Sample5 Dead    [Not Available]            2532
Sample6 Dead    [Not Available]            1271
```

I want to combine columns `last_contact_days_to` and `death_days_to` where in the result it should show only values not any other characters. And if both the columns has characters it should remove the whole row.

The result should look like following:

```
Samples Status  new_column
Sample2 Dead    724
Sample3 Dead    1624
Sample4 Alive   1569
Sample5 Dead    2532
Sample6 Dead    1271
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can change the `[Not Available]` and `[Not Applicable]` to `NA` and use `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   mutate_at(3:4, 
      funs(replace(., .%in% c("[Not Available]", "[Not Applicable]"), NA))) %>%
   transmute(Samples, Status,
             new_column = coalesce(last_contact_days_to, death_days_to)) %>%
   filter(!is.na(new_column))
#  Samples Status new_column
#1 Sample2   Dead        724
#2 Sample3   Dead       1624
#3 Sample4  Alive       1569
#4 Sample5   Dead       2532
#5 Sample6   Dead       1271
```

Note: As @Roland suggested, if the columns 3 and 4 have only numeric values in addition to the '[Not Available]', '[Not Applicable]', then the `mutate_at` can be changed to `as.numeric`.  It will convert all non-numeric elements to `NA` with a friendly warning and it would not have any problems

```
df1 %>%
    mutate_at(3:4, as.numeric) 
    # if the columns are `factor` class then wrap with `as.character`
    # mutate_at(3:4, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))
```

NOTE: In the OP's dataset, these are `factor` class.  So, uncomment the code above and use that instead of directly applying `as.numeric`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Samples = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", 
"Sample5", "Sample6"), Status = c("Alive", "Dead", "Dead", "Alive", 
"Dead", "Dead"), last_contact_days_to = c("[Not Available]", 
"[Not Available]", "[Not Available]", "1569", "[Not Available]", 
"[Not Available]"), death_days_to = c("[Not Applicable]", "724", 
"1624", "[Not Applicable]", "2532", "1271")), .Names = c("Samples", 
"Status", "last_contact_days_to", "death_days_to"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: You don't need `replace` if you just use `as.numeric`.

Comment: @Roland You are right.  I was thinking that the OP may have some other words in addition to numbers

Comment: @akrun oh ya with Roland's suggestion, I got the output I need. Thank you akrun and Roland.

Comment: @akrun sorry there is an error. with as.numeric it didn't remove the first row which is with '[Not Available]', '[Not Applicable]' instead it gave number 216 for that. Dont know why. All the values in the new_column are totally changed now

Comment: @user3351523  I mentioned in the post that if your column is `factor` class, it should be `as.numeric(as.character`.  What you are finding is the integer storage values instead of the actual values

Comment: @user3351523  Also, my initial suggestion with `replace` would work even with that because it converts to `character` class.

Comment: @user3351523  It is the commented line `df1 %>% mutate_at(3:4, funs(as.numeric(as.character(.))))`  BTW,  you are mixing codes from `replace` with `as.numeric`

Comment: Sorry that was a by mistake from me. I'm trying upvote but it is not taking.

Comment: @akrun if you can edit the answer then I would upvote again if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot again for the best solution